# Cross-Platform C++ Dynamic Library Plugin Loader

Tags: c++, plugins, cross-platform, shared-libraries

I was just wondering what my options were for cross-platform implementations for the dynamic loading of plugins using shared libraries. So far the only one that I have found is:

- http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Dynamic-Loading-of-Modules.html

And I was just wondering if I had other options? Essentially, I want to be able to put plugins in shared object files, and load them at runtime and I wanted to do it in a cross-platform C++ way.

**Edit**: I found this [Dr Dobbs Post](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/204202899;jsessionid=B1A3K1QJIH3K3QE1GHPSKHWATMY32JVN?pgno=1) from 2007; surely somebody has come up with something more since then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322/whats-safe-for-a-c-plug-in-system

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could look into [Boost Extension,](http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/index.html) though it has not yet been accepted into Boost.

> The Boost.Extension library has been
>   developed to ease the development of
>   plugins and similar extensions to
>   software using shared libraries.
>   Classes, functions and data can be
>   made available from shared libraries
>   and loaded by the application.

Comment: Nice. I love the Boost Libraries, I'll see how close this is to becoming apart of boost proper.

Comment: Don't do this.  The original author has deprecated his own work.  http://blog.redshoelace.com/2014/01/c0x.html#links

Comment: Since 2016, Boost v1.61.0 has added dll. [Reference](https://www.boost.org/users/history/). [Documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_dll.html) for 1.73.0

Answer (score 3):

Qt has a nice [plugin system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/plugins-howto.html). You should take a look at the [second part](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/plugins-howto.html#the-lower-level-api-extending-qt-applications) of that page.

Comment: Qt would know what they are doing, I should have thought of them, reading now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something simple and lightweight try: https://pocoproject.org/docs/package-Foundation.SharedLibrary.html

Using the SharedLibrary class it takes three lines to call a function in a C shared library:

```
Poco::SharedLibrary lib("libfoo.so");
int (* foo)(int) = reinterpret_cast<int (*)(int)>(lib.getSymbol("foo"));    
printf("answer %d\n", foo(5));
```