# tricky C problem. dynamic function call

Tags: c++, c, function, dynamic, visual-c++

I am writing a program in C/C++(**but c++ class should not be involved**)  which is divided into 2 parts. 
The first is basic need for threads and processes.
The second is for users to customizing their own functions. 
the module is like, what puzzles me is the user-customizing functions.

`My Need is as following:`
Users can create a new ***.c** file in a given folder, they can write their own functions.

after they made their own functions, and compilation, i provide them with an interface maybe via socket or http, or argv command. they can evoke the functions they defined before.
they only give me a string like "own_funciton", and then I call the function they defined.

```
The question is : how to do this? 

How can i connect the strings and the functions???
```

I think maybe MACRO may be a solution,
I ask users to define their function like this:
**This is just an example**

```
BEGIN_FUNCTION (own_funcion)
{
   //function body
}
END_FUNCTION
```

**HEED**:when users add their new functions, whole system need to be recompiled.

you can do something in the MACRO **BEGIN_FUNCTION** to store the function string and the function pointer..
**But I dont know how to write the MACRO specifically..
Do you have any advice**

Comment: Did you consider to use an embedded language, such as Lua, for custom functions?

Comment: but only C is allowed by my boss

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your explanation... but it sounds vaguely to me like you want to write your own scripting language.

Comment: I agree with 9000. Lua is designed to be embedded, has a very small footprint (what, 50k or so?) and is widespread within communities where performance matters (e.g. game development).If you have to reinvent the wheel, you might have what is technically a C-based solution, but only you will understand it!

Comment: -1. Nothing about what the application does, program environment(OS), and what kind of users they are.

Comment: @mikek3332002, it's like the PHP, users define their functions. but i wanto do this C .

Comment: @Macroideal: I think that you might be missing the point. Do you have to compile your whole system after the user adds a new function? Or do you have a running system and the user only adds plugins (C, then compiled, then loaded into an existing system)? If you are not allowed to recompile the whole system, you have to specify the operating system, or any other constraint. Remember, half of the way to a good answer is providing a good question, and that is specifying all the actual constraints on the problem.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: thanx, I after add new functions, the whole system needs to be recompiled. my system is WS or Linux, Pure C is used.

Answer (score 2):

Mh, this sounds a bit like a plugin architecture to me - in this case this question might help you: [What's safe for a C++ plug-in system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322/whats-safe-for-a-c-plug-in-system)
I guess you would need to write some generic plugin and your macro provides the glue to fit in the user defined functions and hiding the complex stuff.

You could also have a look at cppunit (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page) which essentially enables you to write some functions, wrap them in macros which provide the glue to the cppunit framework and then let them run in a generic testrunner. But it doesn't sound like an easy task. Using some scripting language like lua seems way easier.

**Update**: There are some c interpreters out there, for example Cint (http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint). And appartenly TCC (http://bellard.org/tcc/) supports interpreter style calling (I guess it's inline compiling and execution). I have not used these tools that way but they might ease the pain around the "having to compile it into a dynamic dll" problem. Although I still would like to hear the rational to go down such a path instead of using a scripting language like Lua which is way more suitable for those purposes.

Comment: I don't know Macroideal rational, but for example VxWorks has a shell that supports exactly what he is describing: You can load dynamicaly a library and then call from the shell a function typing his name and params. It's incredibly handy for debugging:)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a homework related question on how to deal with dynamic library loading, which is how most *plug-in* systems are built. Read how dynamic library loading is implemented in your platform.

As an example, in linux, you would look at `dlopen`/`dlclose`/`dlsym` functions. Basically the user implements a `.so` object, and when your application loads it opens the `.so` file with `dlopen`, once the library has been loaded, and the user enters a string, you can look for the specific function name with `dlsym` and call it through the function pointer. Once you have finished with the library, you release it with `dlclose`.

There are libraries that can help a bit in here, like Boost.Extension, that provide a multi platform interface to the underlying OS calls.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options

<del>1) If your functions are small, you can make a macro that simply declares a function  and adds function to an map of pointers to functions of your type (typedef your function)</del>

```
int FunctionName()
{
   //user code
}
map["FunctionName"] = FunctionName;
```

<del>a macro that does that is not hard to write</del>

when you want to execute, simply select function function from map and call it

2) you your functions are larger you must consider a plugin system. Dlls that export a function. On "server" you can enum and load those dlls and exect requested function

3) A nice version where be using a script engine that allows users   to execute scrips on the server. You can achieve this my using [IActiveScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky29ffxd%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or one of the many free script engines available.

**Edit**:

4) One more possibility that came in my mind.

- Add your .c files to a dll project.
- Add __declspec( dllexport ) modifier to every function you wnat to add  (eventually trough the macro)
- Enum exported function like this

> ```
> void EnumDllFunctions()
> {
>     BYTE *hMod = (BYTE*)GetModuleHandle("KERNEL32.DLL");
>     IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *pnt = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)&hMod[PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(hMod)->e_lfanew];
>     IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *exp = (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY*)&hMod[pnt->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory->VirtualAddress];
>     DWORD *dwFunctions = (DWORD*)&hMod[exp->AddressOfNames];
>    for (DWORD ctr = 0; ctr < exp->NumberOfNames; ctr++) 
>    {
>        printf("%s\n", (char*)&hMod[dwFunctions[ctr]]);
>    }
> ```

Comment: Thanx for your reply, prefer the 1st option. but i got problems. i write a macro, i store the function reflections in the MACRO, but the MACRO is call outside the realm of functions. outside the functions, giving a variable a value is not permitted in C....any other solutions. thanx

Comment: in all the plugin files, must be included a header. That header can include a function that adds pair name-ptr to map.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for a Foreign Function Interface, for example [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/).