# Replacing a C++ base class method?

Tags: c++

I have seen [Is it possible to replace a method at runtime in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645454/is-it-possible-to-replace-a-method-at-runtime-in-c-c), but I am something of a C++ newbie, and so cannot yet see how (and if) it applies to my case, so I'd like to try asking with my example.

In the example below, assume classes `MyBase`, `A1`, and `A2`, come from some library, and I'm using them in my `main`:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -o test.exe test.cpp

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyBase {
public:
  MyBase() { }
  ~MyBase() { }
  int getBaseVal(int inval) {
    return inval + 5;
  }
};

class A1 : public MyBase {
public:
  A1() : MyBase() { }
  ~A1() { }
  int getVal(int inval) {
    return getBaseVal(inval) + 10;
  }
};

class A2 : public A1 {
public:
  A2() : A1() { }
  ~A2() { }
  int getVal(int inval) {
    return getBaseVal(inval) + 20;
  }
};


int main() {
  A1 _a1 = A1(); A2 _a2 = A2();
  cout << "A1 for 10: " << _a1.getVal(10) << endl;
  cout << "A2 for 10: " << _a2.getVal(10) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now, let's say I would like to leave this library untouched, but I've discovered a bug in `MyBase::getBaseVal`, in that the right value returned should be `inval + 6;` instead of the given `inval + 5;`. So, nothing complicated, but access to the input arguments of the method is needed.

So do I have an option, to define a new function, say:

```
int getNewBaseVal(int inval) {
  return inval + 6;
}
```

.. and then somehow "replace" the old `MyBase::getBaseVal`:

- On a class level (that is, `MyBase` would be "patched"), such that all subsequent instantiations of `A1` and `A2` will ultimately use the `getNewBaseVal` when their `getVal`s are called;
- On an object level, such that only a particular instantiation of, say, `A1` as object (like `_a1`) would ultimately use the `getNewBaseVal` when its `getVal` is called;

... by writing some code at the start of the `main` function?

Comment: So you fully read a previous Q&A asking whether it's possible to replace a method ......... then you asked the exact same question again?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - well, yes; as one, I'm not sure whether the "runtime" qualifier applies here (I'd like to make a "patch" once at start, and not change it dynamically, maybe there are relaxed criteria for that?); secondly, if polymorphism is the answer, I don't really have an idea how I would go about extending only `MyBase`, without having to also extend `A1`, `A2` and the whole inheritance chain - which is what I'd like to avoid, and the main reason for my question.

Comment: Well the long and short of it is that you can't. Get the library author to fix the bug, and build your own forked and fixed version of it in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for that @LightnessRacesinOrbit - feel free to post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long and short of it is that you can't; at least, not within the given constraints (which rule out various sub-optimal hacks, such as Andrey's!).

Get the library author to fix the bug, and build your own forked and fixed version of it in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest you to create an adapter class and use it as the base class for `A` and `B`

```
class MyBaseAdaptor: public MyBase
{
    using MyBase::MyBase; // Inherit constructors

public:
    int getBaseVal(int inval)  // Hide the old method
    {
        // your code here
    }
};
```

But it is better to fix the library.

Comment: Thanks for that, @AndreyNasonov - but then the `A1`, `A2` classes still wouldn't know about  `MyBaseAdaptor`, unless I recode them too, so they inherit from `MyBaseAdaptor`; is that correct?

Comment: Yes, `class A1 : public MyBaseAdaptor`

Comment: @AndreyNasonov: The OP is pointing out, quite correctly, that he'd have to do this for _each and every class in the inheritance tree_, which is not desired. You have not answered the question per the given constraints.